# Create iterator from a Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

I am working on an NLP project using Seq2Seq. I created a data frame from my dataset then created a batch iterator using data loader, see the following code:

```
# creates lists containing each pair
original_word_pairs = [[w for w in l.split('\t')] for l in lines[:num_examples]]
data = pd.DataFrame(original_word_pairs, columns=["src", "trg"])

# conver the data to tensors and pass to the Dataloader 
# to create a batch iterator

class MyData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.data = X
        self.target = y
        # TODO: convert this into torch code is possible
        self.length = [ np.sum(1 - np.equal(x, 0)) for x in X]
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.data[index]
        y = self.target[index]
        x_len = self.length[index]
        return x,y,x_len
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

train_dataset = MyData(input_tensor_train, target_tensor_train)
val_dataset = MyData(input_tensor_val, target_tensor_val)

train_dataset = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                     drop_last=True,
                     shuffle=True)
test_dataset= DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                     drop_last=True,
                     shuffle=True)
```

That is a part of my code, the thing is I want to use the iterators like this

```
for i, batch in enumerate(iterator):
        
        src = batch.src
        trg = batch.trg
```

But I got an error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'src'"
How can I use the iterator and access a specific column?

Comment: it's unclear how did you use `data` here. Have your printed out the `batch` variable?

Comment: I created input and target tensors using `data` like this: `inp_lang = LanguageIndex(data["src"].values.tolist())
targ_lang = LanguageIndex(data["trg"].values.tolist())
# Vectorize the input and target languages
input_tensor = [[inp_lang.word2idx[s] for s in es.split(' ')]  for es in data["src"].values.tolist()]
target_tensor = [[targ_lang.word2idx[s] for s in eng.split(' ')]  for eng in data["trg"].values.tolist()] `           and `LanguageIndex` is a class that creates word --> index mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `__getitem__` in your `Dataset` to return a dictionary:

```py
def __getitem__(self, index):
    x = self.data[index]
    y = self.target[index]
    x_len = self.length[index]
    return {"src": x, "trg": y, "x_len": x_len}
```

The default `collate_fn` of `DataLoader` will take care to provide a dictionary containing batches instead of single observations, but you need to convert `x_len` to a `tensor` into `__getitem__` to make it work (or you can pass a custom `collate_fn`).

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you meant by converting `x_len` to a tensor
`def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.data[index]
        y = self.target[index]
        x_len = self.length[index]
        xx_len = torch.tensor(x_len)
        return {"src": x, "trg": y, "x_len": xx_len}`

If this is what you meant, then I am still getting an error: **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'src'**

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. With the `dict` object you can access the items with, for example, `batch["src"]`.